# Sort Array based on number of character occurrences

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Say I have an arraylist like this:

[24, 15, 55, 101, 555]

How can I sort the array based on the number of "5" 's in the string? And if there are no fives, then then lower number goes first. So the sorted array would be:

[24,101,15,5,555]

Any idea how to do this? Maybe count the number of 5 occurrences and have a 2d array with 1. the actual number 2. number of 5 occurrences? Then sort the arrays based on 2nd column of 2d array? I'm fairly new to java so please bear with me.

Comment: Look into the `Comparable` and `Comparator` interfaces.

Comment: At least give it a try. You will find 100s of answers based on array sorting if you type the title on google.

Comment: And you do not have to use 2D array, you can implement your entire logic inside your `compareTo` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a class that implements the [`Comparator<String>` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).  In the `compare` method, detect the number of `5` characters there.  If the number of `5` characters is equal, then use `Integer.parseInt` to get the numbers and compare them.

Make sure to return a number less than zero, 0, or greater than zero if the first string should compare less than, equal to, or greater than the second string respectively, to fulfill `compare`'s contract.

> int compare(T o1,
>             T o2)
>
> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is
>   less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Then call `Arrays.sort(yourArray, new YourStringComparator());`.

Comment: I read up on Comparator and figured out how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would make two arrays with one containing the numbers without 5s and the other with the numbers with 5s.

Sort both and concatenate the first with the second.

Comment: It will work, but I don't think it's a good approach. `Comparator` should be used instead.

Comment: How would I sort the array with the 5's based on number of 5 occurances?

Answer (score 1):

Here's (1) a really efficient, generic way to do it and (2) a simple and effective way.

(1) In the first sort, I compute and cache the number of occurrences of the digit 5 once per value in the array.  Then I use a generic sort method to sort based on the cached values.  This is better than a custom comparator because the number of occurrences is only computed once per element in the list.

(2) In the second sort, I simply use a custom comparator, which is more simple to implement.

Sorts (3) and (4) do the same thing as (1) and (2) respectively using Strings rather than Integers.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class DigitSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> initInt = Arrays.asList(555, 55, 5, 101, 202);
        final int sortDigit = 5;

        // sort #1
        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>(initInt);
        sort(ints, new ToComparable<Integer, DigitComparable>() {
            @Override                
            public DigitComparable toComparable(Integer number) {
                return number == null ? null : new DigitComparable(number, digitCount(sortDigit, number));
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Results of int generic sort:");
        for (Integer number : ints)
            System.out.println(number);

        // sort #2
        ints = new ArrayList<>(initInt);
        Collections.sort(ints, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer number1, Integer number2) {
                if (number1 == null && number2 == null)
                    return 0;
                if (number1 == null)
                    return -1;
                if (number2 == null)
                    return 1;
                int digitCount1 = digitCount(sortDigit, number1);
                int digitCount2 = digitCount(sortDigit, number2);
                return
                    digitCount1 > 0 && digitCount2 > 0 ? digitCount1 - digitCount2 :
                    digitCount2 > 0 ? -1 :
                    digitCount1 > 0 ? 1 :
                    number1 - number2;
            }
        });
        System.out.println("\nResults of int comparator sort:");
        for (Integer number : ints)
            System.out.println(number);

        List<String> initString = new ArrayList<>(initInt.size());
        for (Integer number : initInt)
            initString.add(number == null ? null : number.toString());

        // sort #3
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(initString);
        sort(strings, new ToComparable<String, DigitComparable>() {
            @Override                
            public DigitComparable toComparable(String number) {
                if (number == null)
                    return null;
                int asInt = Integer.parseInt(number);
                return new DigitComparable(asInt, digitCount(sortDigit, asInt));
            }
        });
        System.out.println("\nResults of string generic sort:");
        for (String number : strings)
            System.out.println(number);

        // sort #4
        strings = new ArrayList<>(initString);
        Collections.sort(strings, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String number1, String number2) {
                if (number1 == null && number2 == null)
                    return 0;
                if (number1 == null)
                    return -1;
                if (number2 == null)
                    return 1;
                int digitCount1 = digitCount(sortDigit, number1);
                int digitCount2 = digitCount(sortDigit, number2);
                return
                    digitCount1 > 0 && digitCount2 > 0 ? digitCount1 - digitCount2 :
                    digitCount2 > 0 ? -1 :
                    digitCount1 > 0 ? 1 :
                    Integer.parseInt(number1) - Integer.parseInt(number2);
            }
        });
        System.out.println("\nResults of string comparator sort:");
        for (String number : strings)
            System.out.println(number);
    }

    private static class DigitComparable implements Comparable<DigitComparable> {
        private final int number, digitCount;

        DigitComparable(int number, int digitCount) {
            this.number = number;
            this.digitCount = digitCount;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(DigitComparable other) {
            return
                digitCount > 0 && other.digitCount > 0 ? digitCount - other.digitCount :
                other.digitCount > 0 ? -1 :
                digitCount > 0 ? 1 :
                number - other.number;
        }
    }

    protected static int digitCount(int digit, String number) {
        char asChar = Character.forDigit(digit, 10);
        int count = 0;
        for (char c : number.toCharArray())
            if (c == asChar)
                ++count;
        return count;
    }

    protected static int digitCount(int digit, int number) {
        number = Math.abs(number);
        int count = 0;
        while (number != 0) {
            if (number % 10 == digit)
                ++count;
            number /= 10;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public interface ToComparable<T, C extends Comparable<? super C>> {
         C toComparable(T t);
    }

    public static <T, C extends Comparable<? super C>> void sort(List<T> list, ToComparable<T, C> function) {
       class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
          final T original;
          final C comparable;

          Pair(T original, C comparable) {
             this.original = original;
             this.comparable = comparable;
          }

          @Override
          public int compareTo(Pair other) {
                return
                  comparable == null && other.comparable == null ? 0 :
                  comparable == null ? -1 :
                  other.comparable == null ? 1 :
                  comparable.compareTo(other.comparable);
          }
       }

       List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
       for (T original : list)
          pairs.add(new Pair(original, function.toComparable(original)));

       Collections.sort(pairs);

       ListIterator<T> iter = list.listIterator();
       for (Pair pair : pairs) {
          iter.next();
          iter.set(pair.original);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am assuming that the elements of the array list are strings. In that case I think you have the right idea. I would use a for each loop to go through each string and create a new 2d array list. Basically have the first dimension of the array contain the number of 5s in each string and the second dimension of the array list contain the numbers 0 to n-1, n being the number of elements in your original array. Then manually sort the first dimension of your array and move the elements of the second array around respective to their 1st dimensional counter parts. When this is done your second array should contain the order of the elements your original array should be in. Use this second array to adjust the order of your original array and return it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it's better to learn existing Java ways to sort than to program everything from scratch.  I bet Java internal algorithms and their implementation are superior.

Comment: True, but this sounds like a homework assignment and I don't know what kind of material he is restricted from using.